# Run apex method with different profile

Tags: apex

is it possible that I can run a method of the controller with other specific user profile not running user? just like System.runAs()

Comment: But why would you need to run using specific profile, because ultimately it will be an user with specific profile who will execute the request !

Comment: No, you can't specifically run a block of code as a different user in live (non-unit-test) code. There may be technical workarounds, such as performing callouts to log in as the other user, but those are simply kludgy at best, and a potential security risk in the worst-case scenario. You may want to ask specifically about what problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: First, Thank you for your prompt response!  Actually, I want to give the access to add picklist value dynamically without giving the Modify all data permission to a user.  So I have written a VF page which assigned sufficient permission to perform this functionality, but the problem when I call remove permission method in which i am removing the assigned permission. I am getting this error.   - Delete failed. First exception on row 0 with id 0Pa23000000dfmMCAQ; first error: FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, You can't revoke your own ability to Manage Profiles and Permission Sets: [Permissions]

Comment: I hope, My previous comment make sense for you. When I look at this. I found that running user don't have the sufficient permission to remove this. So I thought if we could do something that we could run this "remove permission" functionality to the other user profile like Admin.

Comment: Can this not be achieved using Delegated Adminstration (https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=admin_delegate.htm&language=en_US&type=0) ?  Not used it myself in the wild, but may be a place to start...

Comment: @RobCowell - possibly - delegated admin applies only to custom objects and can do setup on any field therein